# Angular Validator function This showing as undefined

Tags: angular, validation, angular-formbuilder

I am using Angular FormBuilder and using my own validation. 
I have a formBuilder...

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  password: ['', [Validators.required, this.matcher.strong]],
  confirmPassword: [''],
  action: 'newUser'
},{ validator: this.checkPasswords });
```

and the checkPasswords function

```
checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
  let pass = group.get('password').value;
  let confirmPassword = group.get('confirmPassword').value;

  this.isTrue = true;
}
```

When I call `this.isTrue` I get the following error. 
`Cannot set property 'isTrue' of undefined`. If I remove the function checkPasswords from the validator, then it works just fine. Why does this happen?

Thanks

Comment: You have mo access to your component from a validator. The only thing a validator can do is interact with the formgroup or formcontrol. The uggly way to solve it is to add `.bind(this)` after your method reference. But consider not using it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Elia, Is there any way around this then? How could I give `this.isTrue` a value when I cannot reference it in the function?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of setting this property?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `this` doing like that because it's out of scope. Let me exemplify:

```
class Foo {
    bar = 'biz'
    a() {
       console.log(this.bar);
        return this.b;
    }
    aWorkaround() {
        return this.b.bind(this);
    }
    b() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
}

const obj = new Foo();

const func = obj.a();
// console shows "biz"
func();
// error: cant access bar of undefined

const funcWorkaround = obj.aWorkaround();
funcWorkaround();
// Console shows "biz"
```

The problem with this, is that you are making your code very confusing, not reusable (imagine using the same validator on other component that don't have this property).

It will work, but if you are needing to do this, probably your are complicating things on your code.